# Send UPDClient message using mac address?

Tags: c#, indy, mac-address, udpclient

I have some code that uses Indy.Sockets.UDPClient to send messages to pcs on a LAN network using the ip address and listening port(which I store in a database):

```
public static void SendMessage(Client pClient)
{
    UDPClient udpClient = new UDPClient();
    udpClient.Host = pClient.ServerIP;
    udpClient.Port = pClient.fListeningOnUDPPort;
    udpClient.SendBuffer(pClient.RestartMessage);
}
```

but requirements have changed and I now need to be able to send messages using the MAC address instead(also stored in database), is it possible to send a similar message using MAC address?

Or is it possible to get the IP address of the PC from the known MAC address?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you can find the IP address with the Mac address (http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) you are able to send him a message using a UDPClient

[This post](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/11/08/Resolve_IP_Address_And_Host_Name_From_MAC_Address_using_CSharp_and_Windows_ARP_Utility.aspx) describes how to resolve IP address from MAC address using `ARP.exe`.

Comment: i tried implementing this code, it only returned 8 devices on my network (which i believe are the servers), but i know there are over 70 physical machines that are not being returned

Comment: This is strange, you should maybe verify that you are able to access to these devices.

Comment: yes i have verified that, i have another piece of sample code which loads all devices on network for a given work group - but i cannot use this because my program will not know the work group name